Using meta verification for a certificate using the on premises API required?
Help with phone verification
I made a Reddit post for my problem you can view it here
Essentially I'm asking if it's required to use the on premises API to assign that cert to my number to use it to send messages to people using a custom phone number
Tried to use postman to assign the cert to my number but it says It's already registered and I can figure out what's required for all of it to work
